# Android show various activities as in pagination

Tags: android, pagination

I am developing an android app in which user has to create profile(register).This registration process spread across many pages when the user click on submit button on the final page data goes in db.I want to show pages as in pagination 
What will be optimal way please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: It seems to me you should be using fragments inside one activity that includes a viewpager

Comment: I was thinking to use fragements under one activity and move back and forth with buttons but I have to data in ,so that user doesnt need to refill .If I use fragments I have to replace with new one its data will be washed away

Comment: That's okay too. Regarding data loss, since you control the fragment change, you can get the fragment information before doing away with it, or you can also save it to sharedpreferences and retrieve it after all pages have been gone through